# How to display Yes and No instead of binary 1 & 0 in fpdf?

Tags: php, html, select, fpdf

I am creating a pdf using fpdf and posting the input from the form. I want the value 1 0 to be yes No in the pdf.I have use this value 0 1 to do some calculation ....I just want to change in pdf...Now the pdf shows 1 for yes and 0 for No

```
<select class="form-control" style="width:120px;" name="need">
  <option value="0" <?php prev_select("need", 0); ?>>No</option>
  <option value="1" <?php prev_select("need", 1); ?>>Yes</option>
</select>

<?php
function prev_select($field, $option){
    if (isset($_POST[$field])){
        if ($_POST[$field] == $option){
            ?> selected="true" <?php
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: In pdf i am showing this value using $_POST["need"]

Comment: May be the easiest way to make your options value in html form yes/no

Comment: How about `$answer = $_POST['need'] ? 'Yes' : 'No';`?

Comment: I tried this...it didnt worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the 2 options value from `0` and `1` to `yes` and `no`

```
 <select class="form-control" style="width:120px;" name="need">
   <option value="no" <?php prev_select("need", 'no'); ?>>No</option>
   <option value="yes" <?php prev_select("need", 'yes'); ?>>Yes</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: OP says _"I have use this value 0 [or] 1 to do some calculation"_ so I don't think this is the best option

Comment: I dont think i can do that because i am using true(1), false(0) to do some calculation ....

Comment: @Mht so you can replace `yes` and `no` with `0` and `1` or `true` and `false` like this `$need = ($_POST['need'] == 'yes') ? true : false;` before make the calculation if @Phil's solution didn't work for you.

Comment: Isn't it possible to just change value from php file where i generate pdf?

Comment: @Mht Of curse you can! This is exactly what you need `$need = ($_POST['need'] == 1) ? 'yes' : 'no';` and then put $need into PDF file!

Comment: Ya,I tried that before and now too...its not showing result....I found the error....I solved thanks )

Comment: @Mht I'm glad your problem solved! Please mark my answer as correct if it helped you thanks!